# django1.11 TypeError: context must be a dict rather than RequestContext

Tags: python, django

Here is my code:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = 'Thanks for your post.'
            user_name = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
            user_city = form.cleaned_data['user_city']
            user_school = form.cleaned_data['user_school']
            user_email = form.cleaned_data['user_email']
            user_message = form.cleaned_data['user_message']
            ctx = {
                'user_name':user_name,
                'user_city':user_city,
                'user_school':user_school,
                'user_email':user_email,
                'user_message':user_message,
                }
        else:
            message = 'Please check the format of your information.'
    else:
        form = forms.ContactForm()
    template = get_template('contact.html')
    request_context = RequestContext(request)
    request_context.push(locals())

    html = template.render(request_context)

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

But I got the following exception:

```
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than RequestContext.
```

How can I modify my code to avoid this error? (my English is poor, sorry)

Comment: are you sure you not wanna use your local variable ctx in template.render like `html = template.render(ctx)` ?

Comment: Try doing it without `locals()`. Right now `request_context` contains itself which may be a problem.

Comment: @mbieren, for some reason, I don't want to use it

Comment: @Alex Hall,sorry,what do you mean?I know request_context is wrong,but I don't know why

Comment: @hey6775 `request_context` is a local variable, which means `locals()` contains `request_context`, so `request_context.push(locals())` makes `"request_context": request_context` part of `request_context`. Point is, don't use `locals()` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Alex Hall,thanks,I see what you mean.But I have uninstall the 1.11 version of the Django,I use the 1.9.5 version of the django,the problem has been solved.When I finish my study task, I will try your method.

Comment: Downgrading two versions is not a solution. You should always try to use the latest software. And `locals()` is generally a hack to be wary of.

Comment: @Alex Hall,okey,I know. I'll try to solve this problem.what's more, I'll be careful with this

Answer (score 5):

Passing a `Context` object to `Template.render()` is deprecated.

Try changing this:

```
request_context = RequestContext(request)
request_context.push(locals())

html = template.render(request_context)
```

To this:

```
html = template.render(context=locals(), request=request)
```